# parse - swift unauthorized error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm new to iOS software development and swift and I'd like to make an app that is similar to instagram. For this I created a VM instance in google cloud with the Network tags parse-1-tcp-443, parse-1-tcp-80. I ran the code above in the newest version of xcode and got those errors. Why do I get unauthorized error when after logging in username, password url are correct?

Allow Arbitrary Loads is set to yes in info.plist

Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "user"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "*********"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://35.19.10.151/parse"
    })

    Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    defaultACL.getPublicReadAccess = true

    PFACL.setDefault(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.background {
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.current()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFrom(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannel(inBackground: "") { (succeeded, error) in // (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) is now (succeeded, error)

        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handle(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpened(withRemoteNotificationPayload: userInfo)
    }
}
}
```

Error:

```
 2017-10-25 13:08:47.984583+0200 ParseStarterProject-Swift[28036:1825625] [Error]: unauthorized (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=0 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized, NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0})
```

If I write "http://35.19.10.151/" instead of "http://35.19.10.151/parse" I get this:

```
 Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})
```